# Django v3 path variable in url issue

Tags: django, url, path

I've been scratching my head on this one a lot.  I feel like the answer is right in front of me but I can't see it.  I'm using django 3 and I have an url that is returning an error.

My Urls is...

```
url(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', views.GraphanaProxyView.as_view(), name='grafanadash'),
```

My View is...

```
class GraphanaProxyView(ProxyView):
upstream = '{{ip.port}}'

def get_proxy_request_headers(self, request):
   headers = super(GraphanaProxyView, self).get_proxy_request_headers(request)
   headers['X-WEBAUTH-USER'] = request.user.username
   return headers
```

I am calling the url from an iframe....

```
<iframe src ="{% url 'grafanadash' %}" width="100%" height="1200px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But I get the following error...

```
NoReverseMatch at /testsite/mt/mtgrafana/
Reverse for 'grafanadash' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['testsite\\/mt\\/(?P<path>.*)$']
```

I know that technically the "path" part doesn't point to anything, but the view is expecting a "path" variable for it to use.  If I just type the address into the bar "/testsite/mt/grafanadash" it routes through the view and works. If I attempt to have it render inside a frame, or just call it through a link is when I get the error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Holy cow!  I just figured it out right after I post the question, go figure.  The answer is in the iframe or url request. It just needed a placeholder for the "path" variable.

```
<iframe src ="{% url 'grafanadash' 'path' %}" width="100%" height="1200px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In retrospect that seems obvious.  Hopefully this is helpful to someone else.